# GGTS 3.1 (Eclipse) Search view is not working

Tags: eclipse

Search view  isn't showing when I use Ctrl+H. It's also not appearing when clicking on menu Search -> Search...

I'm using GGTS 3.1

Other hot-keys are working without problem. I also checked mapping in Preferences, and there is still search view binded to Ctrl + H.

Any idea what's going on with my eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Try to close every ide and kill processes if any one still remain (ggts, sts, javaw).

---

Other search methods are working? (eg. CTRL+SHIFT+G)?

Comment: Still not working. CTRL+SHIFT+G works but it looks only for references. I need this complex search window with text search and other tabs.

Comment: Do u have multiple ide (eclipse, sts, ggts) running in one time?

Comment: Juno 4.2.2 and in this time also eclipse 3.2.